# How to parse the date using Date Filter

Tags: logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

My log message as below

> 2016-04-04T12:51:01.05-0500 [App/0]      OUT [INFO    ] SRVE0250I: Web
>   Module DataWorks has been bound to default_host.

Can someone guide me to write date filter to parse the date in the above message? I also need to convert the date to UTC format after that.

Answer (score 2):

As I can see you are using standard  ISO8601 date format. You can use following logstash config:

```
filter {
        grok {
                match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{GREEDYDATA:another}"]
        }
        date {
                match => [ "timestamp", "ISO8601"  ]
        }
}
```

this will grok your date to  `timestamp` field, and then parse date to UTC to `@timestamp`   field. Read more here: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html